# jquery form validation not working - zip and email

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this jquery code:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#zip").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[0-9]{5}$//)) return true; else return false;",
        message: "invalid zip code"
    });
    jQuery("#email").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+… return true; else return false;",
        message: "invalid email"
    });
});    
</script>

<form action="save.php">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" />
    <input type="submit" name="go" id="go"  value ="go" />
</form>
```

but when i hit the submit button it does not validate the zip and email, it submits the form. Is my "expression" wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Feedback on this form

This concept of a five character, numbers-only postal code will only handle people in the United States.

Other countries have more complicated postal codes, with fewer or more digits required, or with non-numeric characters.  For example, [Canada supports alphanumeric postal codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code#Alphanumeric_postal_codes).

If you are sure you want this website to only work for people in the US, then don't worry about this.  Otherwise I recommend letting that field be more flexible.

#### Code troubles

I think you'll have less of a headache for a simple form like this if you use the built-in validation rules.  It can handle both of these fields very easily.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzMTs/

Source:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#somethingForm").validate();
</script>

<form id="somethingForm" action="save.php">
    <span>E-Mail</span>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required email" />
    <br>
    <span>Zip Code</span>
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"
        class="required digits" minlength="5" maxLength="5" />
    <input type="submit" name="go" id="go"  value ="go" />
</form>
```

[image: Screenshot of form validation for e-mail and simple zip code]